# Is this example of method overriding in Go?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

type Animal int

const (
    Unknown Animal = iota
    Gopher
    Zebra
)

func (a *Animal) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var s string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    switch strings.ToLower(s) {
    default:
        *a = Unknown
    case "gopher":
        *a = Gopher
    case "zebra":
        *a = Zebra
    }

    return nil
}

func (a Animal) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var s string
    switch a {
    default:
        s = "unknown"
    case Gopher:
        s = "gopher"
    case Zebra:
        s = "zebra"
    }

    return json.Marshal(s)
}

func main() {
    blob := `["gopher","armadillo","zebra","unknown","gopher","bee","gopher","zebra"]`
    var zoo []Animal
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(blob), &zoo); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    census := make(map[Animal]int)
    for _, animal := range zoo {
        census[animal] += 1
    }

    fmt.Printf("Zoo Census:\n* Gophers: %d\n* Zebras:  %d\n* Unknown: %d\n",
        census[Gopher], census[Zebra], census[Unknown])

}
```

This is the code snippet of Json custom marshal example in go doc. My question is where is the call to MarshalJSON and UnmarshalJSON method in this code. Are these method somehow overriding Json package's UnmarshalJSON and MarshalJSON method. I thought go does not support method overriding this way. Pls help, i am not able to understand what is happening in this code!!

Comment: You're not "overriding a method" but rather "implementing an interface". The effect, from an extreme-high-level ("30,000 foot overview") perspective, might be the same, but the mechanics are very different.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation says](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal):

> To unmarshal JSON into a value implementing the Unmarshaler interface, Unmarshal calls that value's UnmarshalJSON method, including when the input is a JSON null.

Somewhere in the json.Unmarshal implementation, there's code similar this:

```
 u, ok := v.(Unmarshaler)
 if ok {
     err := u.Unmarshal(data)
     if err != nil { /* handle error */}
 } else {
     // handle other kinds of values
 }
```

The code uses a [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to determine if the value satisfies the [json.Unmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) interface.  If the value does satisfy the method, the value's UnmarshalJSON function is called.

The `(*Animal).UnmarshalJSON` function is called because `*Animal` satisfies the [json.Unmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of implementing an [interface](https://go.dev/tour/methods/9) from a different package.

There's no need to explicitly declare that you're implementing an interface in Go, like there is in Java or C++ for example. You just have to implement all the functions it declares. In this case, you're implementing the [`Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) interface declared in the [`json` package](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) which is used by the [`Unmarshal` function](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal).